# Como usar JQuery para acionar uma função quando o title da pagina for alterado?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Olá, eu sou novo nesta plataforma, não sei se minha pergunta vai cumprir os requisitos, mas vou tentar ser o mais especifico possível!

Eu quero acionar um evento usando o Jquery, para quando o  for alterado, estava tentando usar a seguinte função:

```
$('title').change(function(){
console.log('O titulo foi alterado!')
})
```

Porem quando altero o valor da tag  simplesmente nada acontece, alguém poderia me explicar o motivo disso, ou se for possível me apresentar uma forma valida de se fazer isso.. Desde já agreço :D!

Comment: Voce altera o valor de `title` atraves de um `input`?

Comment: Não, através do devtools

Comment: Na verdade, quero que esse evento seja disparado quando eu receber uma nova mensagem no WhatsApp, quando existe uma mensagem no WhatsApp o título dele é alterado e eu quero capturar esse evento

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> se for possível me apresentar uma forma valida de se fazer isso..

Usando JavaScript puro você pode usar o [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) que é uma API que observa mudanças no DOM e dispara uma funcão quando a detecta.

De exemplo, você seleciona o `title` via `querySelector` e atribui ele a instância `MutationObserver` usando o método `observe`. Passe uma funcão de *callback* para o objeto `MutationObserver` que dispara quando ocorrer uma alteração no `title`.

Código de exemplo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      const title = document.querySelector('title');

      new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
        console.log(mutations[0].target.nodeValue); // mostra o novo valor

        console.log('Title mudou!'); // avisamos que o title mudou
        alert('Title mudou!')
      }).observe(title, { // informamos que ele deve observar 'title'
        subtree: true,
        characterData: true,
        childList: true,
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

<sub>Não sei se essa API é implementada em JQuery.</sub>

Comment: woww! muito obrigado funcionou perfeitamente bem, MUITO OBRIGADO mesmo !

Comment: E se eu quiser observar uma classe por exemplo, isso funcionaria?

Comment: Se fala de um elemento com uma classe especifica sim, basta fazer `const elemento = document.querySelector('.nome-da-classe);`. Passe `.nome-da-classe` para o `querySelector`. Pode ser id, classe, tag, etc...

Comment: Ok muito obrigado!